# create foreign key in different data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key, relationship

I don't know if this is possible or not, and I searched this way but a lot of them just say this is not possible. But, I got a data from internet for studying in a way of copying the case or application and of course it looks like this likely possible to make a relationship for a different data type. Let's take a look for an example.

[image]

Comment: You're suffering from inconsistent table design. Fix those column definitions, and the problem is gone.

Comment: Adding to what jarlh said, you're right that you can't mix the data type of the two columns in the relationship, so you will need to make them the same data type for it to work.

Comment: Agree with above - the most efficient and correct approach. Just in case you can't change the design then a link table between the two fields is possible, each column with the appropriate type. You can also create a view to give you those results. You can also write a view to perform a join and use that. Not efficient or recommended, but possible, even for unrelated types. E.g. SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TableA] A inner join [dbo].[TableB] B on cast(B.[SomeStringField] as varchar) = cast(A.[SomeIntegerField] as varchar)

Comment: What would happen to an order that has an ID that's actually 11 or 12 characters?  It could never have any details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I absolutely agree with those who left comments: the **best answer is to change the type** of OrderDetail.OrderID to match OrderHeader.ID.

Doing **anything else** is a **very bad idea**.

But, assuming that you can't do that for some reason, you can create a foreign key, ... kind of .. sort of.

You can create a computed field that casts the one datatype to the other, and set up a foreign key on that field.  Note, in order to do this, the computed field must be persisted.

```
create table OrderHeader ( ID char(12) primary key )

create table OrderDetail ( OrderID char(10),
                           OrderID12 as cast ( OrderID as char(12) )
                           persisted
                           foreign key references OrderHeader(ID)
                           )

insert into OrderHeader ( ID ) values ( 'MOH333' )

insert into OrderDetail ( OrderID ) values ( 'MOH333' )

-- this one fails
insert into OrderDetail ( OrderID ) values ( '777PIR' )
```